# Can not find plist file in documents directory? How to modify the plist programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I have an application in Xcode 4.2.

I have created plist file as my requirement.

I have found the data from Applications main bundle and got the data in to the array.

But As I want to modify the plist data at run time, I could not find it in Documents Directory

Actually I want to modify the plist programmatically. Though I am not using mainbundle.

```
-(NSString *) saveFilePath::(NSString *)tagString     
{
    NSArray *arr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *strPath = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:tagString];       
    return strPath;
}
```

Could not retrive the plist file.(Path I am getting, but path with file not getting)

I also could not find physically the plist file in the iphone simulator/App/Documents folder?

Comment: Did you copy the plist file to the documents directory?

Comment: What? Xcode 5.0?  There's only Xcode 4.2

Comment: No, I think it is not required Xcode will create automatically plist file.

Comment: @Arpit Can you show us the code where you create the plist?

Comment: Are you basically doing preferences?  If so, it's something that's better done with NSDefaults, which will handle sane defaults, putting the settings in the right place, etc.

Comment: Would you please elaborote this? thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to copy plist from  bundle to document directory  first

```
-(void) checkAndCreateSetting
{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

let  me know in case of any query 
thanks& regards 
neil